# V4L2 and ALSA: Kernel SPI or User API?

Tags: linux, kernel, alsa, api, v4l2

I'm trying to understand what [Video for linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) and [ALSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALSA) are (exactly), and I can't discern whether they're APIs for Linux application to use (the *userspace*) or if they are backend services that are only available to the Linux kernel (sort of a *kernalspace SPI*). Or, if they are something entirely different.

On one hand, those articles make it sound like its an API for applications to use. However, on the V4L2 page it has a section title *Software supporting Video4Linux*...

So is V4L2 a library that applications use, or is it a module that "snaps into" the kernel? I'm so coonfused, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both V4L2 and ALSA are

- a kernel library to make driver programming easier,
- an interface between the kernel and userspace,
- a userspace library to make application programming easier, and
- an interface between the library and applications.

Comment: Thanks @CL. (+1) - so to confirm: both V4L2 and ALSA are used by the kernel as well as as expose an API for applications to use? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I've heard the phrase "if the kernel *supports* V4L2...". If V4L2 really is just a library, then how could a kernel have to *support* it? Why wouldn't you just be able to *install* it on any Linux kernel?

Comment: Yes. It's possible to disable them in the kernel configuration.